# Find words with regEx and then add whitespaces inbetween with Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I was wondering how to add whitespaces inbetween letters/numbers in a string with Objective-C.

I have the sample code kinda working at the moment.  Basically I want to turn "West4thStreet" into "West 4th Street".

```
NSString *myText2 = @"West4thStreet"; 
NSString *regexString2 = @"([a-z.-][^a-z .-])"; 

for(NSString *match2 in [myText2 componentsMatchedByRegex:regexString2 capture:1L]) { 

    NSString *myString = [myText2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:match2 withString:@" "]; 
    NSLog(@"Prints out: %@",myString); // Prints out: Wes thStreet // Prints out: West4t treet   

}
```

So in this example, it's replacing what I found in regEx (the "t4" and "hS") with spaces.  But I just want to add a space inbetween the letters to separate out the words.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap parts of your regex patterns in parentheses, you can refer to them as $1, $2, etc in your replacement string (patterns are numbered from left to right, by the order of their opening parenthesis).

```
NSString *origString = @"West4thStreet";
NSString *newString = [origString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"(4th)" withString:@" $1 "];
```

Not sure I understand your broader use case, but that should at least get you going...

Comment: Hey skue, that definitely helps.  I basically have a bunch of subway stops, that are all hashtagged, like #West4thStreet or #UnionSquare, and I'm passing them off as titles in navControllers, but I don't want it to appear as "#West4thStreet" in the header title.  I want it to just appear as "West 4th Street," like how it normally would.

Comment: I think I figured it out:

NSString *myText2 = @"West4thStreet"; 
NSString *myString = [myText2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"(([A-Z]|[1-9][0-9]*)[a-z]*)(([A-Z]|[1-9][0-9]*)[a-z]*)(([A-Z]|[1-9][0-9]*)[a-z]*)?" withString:@"$1 $3 $5"];
NSLog(@"Prints out: %@",myString);

Comment: Interesting. Sure you don't need the second digit to be optional in the first pattern too? Ex: #2ndAvenue. You can also handle ordinals as a special case `(\\d+(st|nd|rd|th))` and do multiple passes if necessary.

Comment: Oh good call...so would the updated regEx look like: (([A-Z]|[1-9][0-9]*)[a-z]*)?(([A-Z]|[1-9][0-9]*)[a-z]*)(([A-Z]|[1-9][0-9]*)[a-z]*)(([A-Z]|[1-9][0-9]*)[a-z]*)?

Comment: Sure, but do you have a copy of all the hashtags somewhere? Best way to be sure is to process a sample file and check the output. If you do run into probs, an alternate strategy is to do two regexes in succession looking for transitions (rather than trying to match full words/numbers): `@"([a-z])([A-Z0-9])"` -> `@"$1 $2"` then `@"([0-9])([A-Z])"` -> `@"$1 $2"`.